# Listview with a exact number of visible items regardless of screen size

Tags: android, listview

So ill try to explain what i need to do:
I'm trying to create a list view that always displays only 4 rows on the screen, no matter the size of the screen - so i need to somehow adjust the size of a list row based on the screen height. Also i would like my list view not to stop "in the middle" of a row after scrolling - i want it to "clip" to the nearest edge of a row. Can anyone point me in the right direction since i have no clue how to start at the moment.

I know that clipping can by achieved with `smoothScrollToPosition()` but how can i determine if if top row bottom edge or bottom row top edge is closer to the edge of the screen?

Comment: Don't use à listView, if you want 4elements you should simply use button or image button in a linear layout

Answer (score 0):

Task seems too strange. Do you still need scrolling? what is the total amount of items there? Do you really need a listview?
Consider not using listview at all, but dynamically fill a container with Items

Comment: Yes i need scrolling. I have about 20 elements there. After we stop scrolling i need the list to clip to the nearest edge so we don't "cut" rows in half and so 4 full elements are visible on the screen